# How to create multiple columns for numbered lists in WordPress? CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, list, html-lists

What's the best way to display multiple columns for a long numbered (ul) list in WordPress using CSS? Many answers exist for creating columns for unordered ul lists but I can't seem to find anything that addresses multi-column displays for numbered lists.

For example a page like https://wtfyi.com/best-bands-of-all-time/ that has a huge numbered list. How would you make a list like that display in 2 or 3 columns?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS Grid :

```
ol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; // Three Columns
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works great and keeps the number order in a logical user friendly sequence for readers scanning the multiple columns.

Comment: Works nicely but does not look to be responsive for smaller screen sizes. So on small phone screen it shows 3 columns does not wrap # of columns to ideally fit screen size.

Comment: I added a custom class .multicol for the list and tested it out with these screens width value and it works pretty nicely. Auto resizes as you drag the screen smaller changing from 3 to 2 to 1 columns while shrinking browser window from 1920 screen.

`
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .multicol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .multicol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .multicol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  }
}
`

Answer (score 2):

You can set columns' number as per your requirement using css. This can be used for ul and ol both.

```css
ol{
  columns:3;
}
ol li {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Led Zeppelin</li>
    <li>Queen</li>
    <li>The Beatles</li>
    <li>Pink Floyd</li>
    <li>The Rolling Stones</li>
    <li>Jimi Hendrix</li>
    <li>AC/DC</li>
    <li>The Who</li>
    <li>The Eagles</li>
    <li>Guns N’ Roses</li>
    <li>Creedence Clearwater Revival</li>
    <li>Black Sabbath</li>
    <li>David Bowie</li>
    <li>Fleetwood Mac</li>
    <li>Elvis Presley</li>
    <li>Van Halen</li>
    <li>Nirvana</li>
    <li>Aerosmith</li>
    <li>Metallica</li>
    <li>The Doors</li>
    <li>Lynyrd Skynyrd</li>
    <li>Eric Clapton</li>
    <li>Tom Petty and the Heartbreakers</li>
    <li>Rush</li>
    <li>The Jimi Hendrix Experience</li>
    <li>The Police</li>
    <li>Red Hot Chili Peppers</li>
    <li>Deep Purple</li>
    <li>Pearl Jam</li>
    <li>Chuck Berry</li>
    <li>ZZ Top</li>
    <li>Cream</li>
    <li>Dire Straits</li>
    <li>The Kinks</li>
    <li>Bob Dylan</li>
    <li>Journey</li>
    <li>Foo Fighters</li>
    <li>John Lennon</li>
    <li>Simon and Garfunkel</li>
    <li>Paul McCartney</li>
    <li>Iron Maiden</li>
    <li>Santana</li>
    <li>Boston</li>
    <li>Heart</li>
    <li>Electric Light Orchestra</li>
    <li>Def Leppard</li>
    <li>Ozzy Osbourne</li>
    <li>Neil Young</li>
    <li>Genesis</li>
    <li>R.E.M.</li>
    <li>Bon Jovi</li>
    <li>Stevie Ray Vaughan</li>
    <li>The Allman Brothers Band</li>
    <li>Buddy Holly</li>
    <li>Billy Joel</li>
    <li>George Harrison</li>
    <li>Foreigner</li>
    <li>The Cars</li>
    <li>Soundgarden</li>
    <li>Steve Miller Band</li>
    <li>Bob Seger &amp; the Silver Bullet Band</li>
    <li>Crosby, Stills, Nash</li>
    <li>The Animals</li>
    <li>Alice Cooper</li>
    <li>The Moody Blues</li>
    <li>Chicago</li>
    <li>Alice in Chains</li>
    <li>The Doobie Brothers</li>
    <li>Paul McCartney and Wings</li>
    <li>Roy Orbison</li>
    <li>Robert Plant</li>
    <li>Neil Young &amp; Crazy Horse</li>
    <li>The Pretenders</li>
    <li>Buddy Holly and the Crickets</li>
    <li>Jefferson Airplane</li>
    <li>Blondie</li>
    <li>Joan Jett and the Blackhearts</li>
    <li>Janis Joplin</li>
    <li>Joe Walsh</li>
    <li>Phil Collins</li>
    <li>Derek and the Dominos</li>
    <li>George Thorogood &amp; The Destroyers</li>
    <li>Steppenwolf</li>
    <li>John Fogerty</li>
    <li>The Hollies</li>
    <li>Toto</li>
    <li>The Guess Who</li>
    <li>The Mamas &amp; The Papas</li>
    <li>Steve Miller</li>
    <li>The Cranberries</li>
    <li>Bad Company</li>
    <li>Bachman–Turner Overdrive</li>
    <li>Yes</li>
    <li>Steely Dan</li>
    <li>The Byrds</li>
    <li>Blue Öyster Cult</li>
    <li>David Gilmour</li>
    <li>Supertramp</li>
    <li>Joe Cocker</li>
    <li>Traveling Wilburys</li>
    <li>REO Speedwagon</li>
    <li>Scorpions</li>
    <li>Billy Idol</li>
    <li>The Beach Boys</li>
    <li>Elvis Costello &amp; The Attractions</li>
    <li>The Yardbirds</li>
    <li>Mötley Crüe</li>
    <li>Talking Heads</li>
    <li>Styx</li>
    <li>Three Dog Night</li>
    <li>The Four Seasons</li>
    <li>The Zombies</li>
    <li>Green Day</li>
    <li>Linkin Park</li>
    <li>Don Henley</li>
    <li>Peter Frampton</li>
    <li>Pat Benatar</li>
    <li>Pretenders</li>
    <li>Kansas</li>
    <li>Cat Stevens</li>
    <li>Paul Simon</li>
    <li>Thin Lizzy</li>
    <li>Buffalo Springfield</li>
    <li>Motörhead</li>
    <li>Otis Redding</li>
    <li>Pete Townshend</li>
    <li>America</li>
    <li>Sting</li>
    <li>T. Rex</li>
    <li>Debbie Harry</li>
    <li>Ramones</li>
    <li>Jethro Tull</li>
    <li>The Cure</li>
    <li>The Clash</li>
    <li>Rod Stewart</li>
    <li>Tina Turner</li>
    <li>Eric Burdon &amp; The Animals</li>
    <li>Hall &amp; Oates</li>
    <li>Cheap Trick</li>
    <li>The J. Geils Band</li>
    <li>Bruce Springsteen</li>
    <li>Grand Funk Railroad</li>
    <li>Judas Priest</li>
    <li>Joan Jett</li>
    <li>Kiss</li>
    <li>Bryan Adams</li>
    <li>INXS</li>
    <li>Jackson Browne</li>
    <li>Huey Lewis &amp; the News</li>
    <li>The Bangles</li>
    <li>Steve Winwood</li>
    <li>Peter Gabriel</li>
    <li>Emerson, Lake &amp; Palmer</li>
    <li>John Mellencamp</li>
    <li>Mick Jagger</li>
    <li>Stone Temple Pilots</li>
    <li>Eurythmics</li>
    <li>George Thorogood</li>
    <li>Grateful Dead</li>
    <li>Radiohead</li>
    <li>The Smashing Pumpkins</li>
    <li>Dio</li>
    <li>Foghat</li>
    <li>Jeff Beck</li>
    <li>Men at Work</li>
    <li>Frank Zappa</li>
    <li>The Turtles</li>
    <li>Badfinger</li>
    <li>The Monkees</li>
    <li>Traffic</li>
    <li>Rage Against the Machine</li>
    <li>Eddie Money</li>
    <li>Bill Haley &amp; His Comets</li>
    <li>Iron Butterfly</li>
    <li>The Marshall Tucker Band</li>
    <li>Iggy Pop</li>
    <li>Nazareth</li>
    <li>Tool</li>
    <li>Sweet</li>
    <li>Roger Waters</li>
    <li>Oasis</li>
    <li>Manfred Mann</li>
    <li>Meat Loaf</li>
    <li>Molly Hatchet</li>
    <li>The White Stripes</li>
    <li>The Band</li>
    <li>Procol Harum</li>
    <li>Stray Cats</li>
    <li>Them</li>
    <li>Ringo Starr</li>
    <li>The Alan Parsons Project</li>
    <li>The Jeff Beck Group</li>
    <li>Eddie Cochran</li>
    <li>Lou Reed</li>
    <li>Rainbow</li>
    <li>Blind Faith</li>
    <li>Tears for Fears</li>
    <li>Alice in Chains</li>
    <li>The Lovin’ Spoonful</li>
    <li>The Spencer Davis Group</li>
    <li>Depeche Mode</li>
    <li>Free</li>
    <li>Jefferson Starship</li>
    <li>Ten Years After</li>
    <li>The Black Crowes</li>
    <li>Canned Heat</li>
    <li>Jerry Lee Lewis</li>
    <li>Whitesnake</li>
    <li>Michael Jackson</li>
    <li>Clash</li>
    <li>James Gang</li>
    <li>Golden Earring</li>
    <li>38 Special</li>
    <li>Survivor</li>
    <li>Mott the Hoople</li>
    <li>Keith Richards</li>
    <li>Kool &amp; the Gang</li>
    <li>Harry Nilsson</li>
    <li>Faces</li>
    <li>Little Feat</li>
    <li>The Knack</li>
    <li>Audioslave</li>
    <li>James Taylor</li>
    <li>Quiet Riot</li>
    <li>The Cult</li>
    <li>Billy Squier</li>
    <li>Mark Knopfler</li>
    <li>Loverboy</li>
    <li>John Mayall</li>
    <li>Robin Trower</li>
    <li>Blood, Sweat &amp; Tears</li>
    <li>Lenny Kravitz</li>
    <li>Collective Soul</li>
    <li>Kurt Cobain</li>
    <li>Roger Daltrey</li>
    <li>Brian Wilson</li>
    <li>Albert King</li>
    <li>Leon Russell</li>
    <li>Nine Inch Nails</li>
    <li>The Offspring</li>
    <li>Edgar Winter</li>
    <li>Ike &amp; Tina Turner</li>
    <li>Elmore James</li>
    <li>The Small Faces</li>
    <li>U2</li>
    <li>The Smiths</li>
    <li>John Mayall &amp; the Bluesbreakers</li>
    <li>Don McLean</li>
    <li>Night Ranger</li>
    <li>System of a Down</li>
    <li>Led Zeppelin</li>
    <li>Queen</li>
    <li>The Beatles</li>
    <li>Pink Floyd</li>
    <li>The Rolling Stones</li>
    <li>Jimi Hendrix</li>
    <li>AC/DC</li>
    <li>The Who</li>
    <li>The Eagles</li>
    <li>Guns N’ Roses</li>
    <li>Creedence Clearwater Revival</li>
    <li>Black Sabbath</li>
    <li>David Bowie</li>
    <li>Fleetwood Mac</li>
    <li>Elvis Presley</li>
    <li>Van Halen</li>
    <li>Nirvana</li>
    <li>Aerosmith</li>
    <li>Metallica</li>
    <li>The Doors</li>
    <li>Lynyrd Skynyrd</li>
    <li>Eric Clapton</li>
    <li>Tom Petty and the Heartbreakers</li>
    <li>Rush</li>
    <li>The Jimi Hendrix Experience</li>
    <li>The Police</li>
    <li>Red Hot Chili Peppers</li>
    <li>Deep Purple</li>
    <li>Pearl Jam</li>
    <li>Chuck Berry</li>
    <li>ZZ Top</li>
    <li>Cream</li>
    <li>Dire Straits</li>
    <li>The Kinks</li>
    <li>Bob Dylan</li>
    <li>Journey</li>
    <li>Foo Fighters</li>
    <li>John Lennon</li>
    <li>Simon and Garfunkel</li>
    <li>Paul McCartney</li>
    <li>Iron Maiden</li>
    <li>Santana</li>
    <li>Boston</li>
    <li>Heart</li>
    <li>Electric Light Orchestra</li>
    <li>Def Leppard</li>
    <li>Ozzy Osbourne</li>
    <li>Neil Young</li>
    <li>Genesis</li>
    <li>R.E.M.</li>
    <li>Bon Jovi</li>
    <li>Stevie Ray Vaughan</li>
    <li>The Allman Brothers Band</li>
    <li>Buddy Holly</li>
    <li>Billy Joel</li>
    <li>George Harrison</li>
    <li>Foreigner</li>
    <li>The Cars</li>
    <li>Soundgarden</li>
    <li>Steve Miller Band</li>
    <li>Bob Seger &amp; the Silver Bullet Band</li>
    <li>Crosby, Stills, Nash</li>
    <li>The Animals</li>
    <li>Alice Cooper</li>
    <li>The Moody Blues</li>
    <li>Chicago</li>
    <li>Alice in Chains</li>
    <li>The Doobie Brothers</li>
    <li>Paul McCartney and Wings</li>
    <li>Roy Orbison</li>
    <li>Robert Plant</li>
    <li>Neil Young &amp; Crazy Horse</li>
    <li>The Pretenders</li>
    <li>Buddy Holly and the Crickets</li>
    <li>Jefferson Airplane</li>
    <li>Blondie</li>
    <li>Joan Jett and the Blackhearts</li>
    <li>Janis Joplin</li>
    <li>Joe Walsh</li>
    <li>Phil Collins</li>
    <li>Derek and the Dominos</li>
    <li>George Thorogood &amp; The Destroyers</li>
    <li>Steppenwolf</li>
    <li>John Fogerty</li>
    <li>The Hollies</li>
    <li>Toto</li>
    <li>The Guess Who</li>
    <li>The Mamas &amp; The Papas</li>
    <li>Steve Miller</li>
    <li>The Cranberries</li>
    <li>Bad Company</li>
    <li>Bachman–Turner Overdrive</li>
    <li>Yes</li>
    <li>Steely Dan</li>
    <li>The Byrds</li>
    <li>Blue Öyster Cult</li>
    <li>David Gilmour</li>
    <li>Supertramp</li>
    <li>Joe Cocker</li>
    <li>Traveling Wilburys</li>
    <li>REO Speedwagon</li>
    <li>Scorpions</li>
    <li>Billy Idol</li>
    <li>The Beach Boys</li>
    <li>Elvis Costello &amp; The Attractions</li>
    <li>The Yardbirds</li>
    <li>Mötley Crüe</li>
    <li>Talking Heads</li>
    <li>Styx</li>
    <li>Three Dog Night</li>
    <li>The Four Seasons</li>
    <li>The Zombies</li>
    <li>Green Day</li>
    <li>Linkin Park</li>
    <li>Don Henley</li>
    <li>Peter Frampton</li>
    <li>Pat Benatar</li>
    <li>Pretenders</li>
    <li>Kansas</li>
    <li>Cat Stevens</li>
    <li>Paul Simon</li>
    <li>Thin Lizzy</li>
    <li>Buffalo Springfield</li>
    <li>Motörhead</li>
    <li>Otis Redding</li>
    <li>Pete Townshend</li>
    <li>America</li>
    <li>Sting</li>
    <li>T. Rex</li>
    <li>Debbie Harry</li>
    <li>Ramones</li>
    <li>Jethro Tull</li>
    <li>The Cure</li>
    <li>The Clash</li>
    <li>Rod Stewart</li>
    <li>Tina Turner</li>
    <li>Eric Burdon &amp; The Animals</li>
    <li>Hall &amp; Oates</li>
    <li>Cheap Trick</li>
    <li>The J. Geils Band</li>
    <li>Bruce Springsteen</li>
    <li>Grand Funk Railroad</li>
    <li>Judas Priest</li>
    <li>Joan Jett</li>
    <li>Kiss</li>
    <li>Bryan Adams</li>
    <li>INXS</li>
    <li>Jackson Browne</li>
    <li>Huey Lewis &amp; the News</li>
    <li>The Bangles</li>
    <li>Steve Winwood</li>
    <li>Peter Gabriel</li>
    <li>Emerson, Lake &amp; Palmer</li>
    <li>John Mellencamp</li>
    <li>Mick Jagger</li>
    <li>Stone Temple Pilots</li>
    <li>Eurythmics</li>
    <li>George Thorogood</li>
    <li>Grateful Dead</li>
    <li>Radiohead</li>
    <li>The Smashing Pumpkins</li>
    <li>Dio</li>
    <li>Foghat</li>
    <li>Jeff Beck</li>
    <li>Men at Work</li>
    <li>Frank Zappa</li>
    <li>The Turtles</li>
    <li>Badfinger</li>
    <li>The Monkees</li>
    <li>Traffic</li>
    <li>Rage Against the Machine</li>
    <li>Eddie Money</li>
    <li>Bill Haley &amp; His Comets</li>
    <li>Iron Butterfly</li>
    <li>The Marshall Tucker Band</li>
    <li>Iggy Pop</li>
    <li>Nazareth</li>
    <li>Tool</li>
    <li>Sweet</li>
    <li>Roger Waters</li>
    <li>Oasis</li>
    <li>Manfred Mann</li>
    <li>Meat Loaf</li>
    <li>Molly Hatchet</li>
    <li>The White Stripes</li>
    <li>The Band</li>
    <li>Procol Harum</li>
    <li>Stray Cats</li>
    <li>Them</li>
    <li>Ringo Starr</li>
    <li>The Alan Parsons Project</li>
    <li>The Jeff Beck Group</li>
    <li>Eddie Cochran</li>
    <li>Lou Reed</li>
    <li>Rainbow</li>
    <li>Blind Faith</li>
    <li>Tears for Fears</li>
    <li>Alice in Chains</li>
    <li>The Lovin’ Spoonful</li>
    <li>The Spencer Davis Group</li>
    <li>Depeche Mode</li>
    <li>Free</li>
    <li>Jefferson Starship</li>
    <li>Ten Years After</li>
    <li>The Black Crowes</li>
    <li>Canned Heat</li>
    <li>Jerry Lee Lewis</li>
    <li>Whitesnake</li>
    <li>Michael Jackson</li>
    <li>Clash</li>
    <li>James Gang</li>
    <li>Golden Earring</li>
    <li>38 Special</li>
    <li>Survivor</li>
    <li>Mott the Hoople</li>
    <li>Keith Richards</li>
    <li>Kool &amp; the Gang</li>
    <li>Harry Nilsson</li>
    <li>Faces</li>
    <li>Little Feat</li>
    <li>The Knack</li>
    <li>Audioslave</li>
    <li>James Taylor</li>
    <li>Quiet Riot</li>
    <li>The Cult</li>
    <li>Billy Squier</li>
    <li>Mark Knopfler</li>
    <li>Loverboy</li>
    <li>John Mayall</li>
    <li>Robin Trower</li>
    <li>Blood, Sweat &amp; Tears</li>
    <li>Lenny Kravitz</li>
    <li>Collective Soul</li>
    <li>Kurt Cobain</li>
    <li>Roger Daltrey</li>
    <li>Brian Wilson</li>
    <li>Albert King</li>
    <li>Leon Russell</li>
    <li>Nine Inch Nails</li>
    <li>The Offspring</li>
    <li>Edgar Winter</li>
    <li>Ike &amp; Tina Turner</li>
    <li>Elmore James</li>
    <li>The Small Faces</li>
    <li>U2</li>
    <li>The Smiths</li>
    <li>John Mayall &amp; the Bluesbreakers</li>
    <li>Don McLean</li>
    <li>Night Ranger</li>
    <li>System of a Down</li>
    <li>Midnight Oil</li>
    <li>The Grass Roots</li>
    <li>Lita Ford</li>
    <li>Freddie King</li>
    <li>Johnny Winter</li>
    <li>The Romantics</li>
    <li>Rory Gallagher</li>
    <li>Little River Band</li>
    <li>Ritchie Valens</li>
    <li>Carl Perkins</li>
    <li>Herman’s Hermits</li>
    <li>The Squids</li>
    <li>Evanescence</li>
    <li>Warren Zevon</li>
    <li>J.J. Cale</li>
    <li>Dave Mason</li>
    <li>The Edgar Winter Group</li>
    <li>Charlie Daniels</li>
    <li>The Killers</li>
    <li>Glen Miller</li>
    <li>Randy Rhoads</li>
    <li>Uriah Heep</li>
    <li>Gary Numan</li>
    <li>Waylon Jennings</li>
    <li>Lionel Richie</li>
    <li>Todd Rundgren</li>
    <li>The Mothers of Invention</li>
    <li>The Ventures</li>
    <li>Megadeth</li>
    <li>Peter Green</li>
    <li>Bonnie Raitt</li>
    <li>Sheryl Crow</li>
    <li>Stephen Stills</li>
    <li>Leonard Cohen</li>
    <li>Gregg Allman</li>
    <li>Gary Moore</li>
    <li>Les Paul</li>
    <li>Ry Cooder</li>
    <li>Hot Tuna</li>
    <li>Manfred Mann’s Earth Band</li>
    <li>Patti Smith</li>
    <li>Suzi Quatro</li>
    <li>Sammy Hagar</li>
    <li>Bill Withers</li>
    <li>Roxy Music</li>
    <li>Jan and Dean</li>
    <li>Dion</li>
    <li>Siouxsie Sioux</li>
    <li>Bread</li>
    <li>Steve Perry</li>
    <li>Joe Jackson</li>
    <li>Rick Wakeman</li>
    <li>Paul Rodgers</li>
    <li>War</li>
    <li>Kenny Loggins</li>
    <li>Echo &amp; the Bunnymen</li>
    <li>Slash</li>
    <li>Bryan Ferry</li>
    <li>Alanis Morissette</li>
    <li>Gerry Rafferty</li>
    <li>Mungo Jerry</li>
    <li>Norman Greenbaum</li>
    <li>T-Bone Walker</li>
    <li>Graham Nash</li>
    <li>Paul Revere and The Raiders</li>
    <li>The Big Bopper</li>
    <li>Muse</li>
    <li>Tommy Dorsey</li>
    <li>Dr. John</li>
    <li>Buffalo</li>
    <li>Peter Tosh</li>
    <li>Marianne Faithfull</li>
    <li>Orchestral Manoeuvres in the Dark</li>
    <li>Ted Nugent</li>
    <li>Slade</li>
    <li>The Tubes</li>
    <li>Sex Pistols</li>
    <li>Bill Bruford</li>
    <li>Spirit</li>
    <li>Steve Howe</li>
    <li>The Highwaymen</li>
    <li>Phil Ochs</li>
    <li>Joan Armatrading</li>
    <li>Seals and Crofts</li>
    <li>Gary Wright</li>
    <li>The Boomtown Rats</li>
    <li>Twisted Sister</li>
    <li>Elvis Costello</li>
    <li>George Benson</li>
    <li>Lindsey Buckingham</li>
    <li>Joy Division</li>
    <li>The Outfield</li>
    <li>J. J. Cale</li>
    <li>Jack White</li>
    <li>Anderson Bruford Wakeman Howe</li>
    <li>John Cafferty &amp; The Beaver Brown Band</li>
    <li>Rammstein</li>
    <li>The Black Keys</li>
    <li>Poison</li>
    <li>Suzanne Vega</li>
    <li>Syd Barrett</li>
    <li>Train</li>
    <li>Funkadelic</li>
    <li>Spooky Tooth</li>
    <li>Budgie</li>
    <li>Aphrodite’s Child</li>
    <li>The Velvet Underground</li>
    <li>Jerry Garcia</li>
    <li>The Commodores</li>
    <li>Weezer</li>
    <li>Madness</li>
    <li>Mike + The Mechanics</li>
    <li>Gary Puckett &amp; The Union Gap</li>
    <li>10cc</li>
    <li>Nena</li>
    <li>Patti Smith Group</li>
    <li>A Flock of Seagulls</li>
    <li>Chris Isaak</li>
    <li>Stealers Wheel</li>
    <li>Ace Frehley</li>
    <li>Rick Derringer</li>
    <li>Pantera</li>
    <li>Joe Satriani</li>
    <li>Soft Cell</li>
    <li>Sha Na Na</li>
    <li>Pixies</li>
    <li>Christopher Cross</li>
    <li>David Lee Roth</li>
    <li>Thelonious Monk</li>
    <li>Humble Pie</li>
    <li>Mountain</li>
    <li>Rick James</li>
    <li>Tom Waits</li>
    <li>The Runaways</li>
    <li>Neal Schon</li>
    <li>The Jam</li>
    <li>Nick Lowe</li>
    <li>Julian Lennon</li>
    <li>Tommy Tutone</li>
    <li>Los Lobos</li>
    <li>Jerry Garcia Band</li>
    <li>Jerry Reed</li>
    <li>The Average White Band</li>
    <li>Arctic Monkeys</li>
    <li>The Clovers</li>
    <li>P!nk</li>
    <li>Strawberry Alarm Clock</li>
    <li>Randy Newman</li>
    <li>The Troggs</li>
    <li>Nick Cave</li>
    <li>Argent</li>
    <li>The Association</li>
    <li>The Chordettes</li>
    <li>The Stooges</li>
    <li>Edie Brickell &amp; New Bohemians</li>
    <li>Violent Femmes</li>
    <li>? &amp; the Mysterians</li>
    <li>The Smithereens</li>
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>Simple Minds</li>
    <li>Siouxsie &amp; the Banshees</li>
    <li>Bruce Hornsby &amp; The Range</li>
    <li>Colosseum</li>
    <li>The Del-Vikings</li>
    <li>Wishbone Ash</li>
    <li>Richie Havens</li>
    <li>The Tremeloes</li>
    <li>Elvin Bishop</li>
    <li>Rick Springfield</li>
    <li>King Crimson</li>
    <li>Vanilla Fudge</li>
    <li>The Kingsmen</li>
    <li>Donald Fagen</li>
    <li>Alphaville</li>
    <li>Robbie Robertson</li>
    <li>Focus</li>
    <li>Talk Talk</li>
    <li>Ian Hunter</li>
    <li>We Five</li>
    <li>Gipsy Kings</li>
    <li>Redbone</li>
    <li>The Rascals</li>
    <li>David Crosby</li>
    <li>Laura Branigan</li>
    <li>Thomas Dolby</li>
    <li>Mr. Mister</li>
    <li>Blink-182</li>
    <li>Ronnie Wood</li>
    <li>Jan Hammer</li>
    <li>Hank Williams, Jr.</li>
    <li>Erasure</li>
    <li>Boz Scaggs</li>
    <li>Split Enz</li>
    <li>Bay City Rollers</li>
    <li>Davy Jones</li>
    <li>Lou Gramm</li>
    <li>Wang Chung</li>
    <li>John Cale</li>
    <li>The Ink Spots</li>
    <li>David Essex</li>
    <li>3 Doors Down</li>
    <li>Big Brother and the Holding Company</li>
    <li>Frankie Goes to Hollywood</li>
    <li>Barry McGuire</li>
    <li>Air Supply</li>
    <li>Jane’s Addiction</li>
    <li>Roxette</li>
    <li>The Searchers</li>
    <li>Herbie Hancock</li>
    <li>Hot Chocolate</li>
    <li>The Fabulous Thunderbirds</li>
    <li>Alicia Keys</li>
    <li>Faith No More</li>
    <li>Steve Hackett</li>
    <li>Gerry &amp; The Pacemakers</li>
    <li>Strawbs</li>
    <li>Fine Young Cannibals</li>
    <li>Janis Ian</li>
    <li>Triumph</li>
    <li>Men Without Hats</li>
    <li>Juice Newton</li>
    <li>Louis Jordan</li>
    <li>Prefab Sprout</li>
    <li>Kate Bush</li>
    <li>The Shirelles</li>
    <li>Of Monsters and Men</li>
    <li>Florence and the Machine</li>
    <li>Barclay James Harvest</li>
    <li>Queens of the Stone Age</li>
    <li>The Pogues</li>
    <li>Be Bop Deluxe</li>
    <li>Culture Club</li>
    <li>The Buggles</li>
    <li>Richard Thompson</li>
    <li>Eddie Vedder</li>
    <li>Gary Lewis &amp; The Playboys</li>
    <li>Disturbed</li>
    <li>Nico</li>
    <li>Duffy</li>
    <li>Scott McKenzie</li>
    <li>The Miracles</li>
    <li>Patrick Moraz</li>
    <li>Juluka</li>
    <li>Bruce Cockburn</li>
    <li>Velvet Revolver</li>
    <li>The Seeds</li>
    <li>The Firm</li>
    <li>Dixie Dregs</li>
    <li>Serge Gainsbourg</li>
    <li>Brian Eno</li>
    <li>Enigma</li>
    <li>Peter Schilling</li>
    <li>The Raspberries</li>
    <li>Sublime</li>
    <li>Chris Rea</li>
    <li>The Proclaimers</li>
    <li>The Quarrymen</li>
    <li>Starship</li>
    <li>Queensrÿche</li>
    <li>Misfits</li>
    <li>The Walker Brothers</li>
    <li>Dick Dale</li>
    <li>Nick Cave and the Bad Seeds</li>
    <li>Jean Michel Jarre</li>
    <li>Black</li>
    <li>The Seekers</li>
    <li>Coldplay</li>
    <li>Soul Asylum</li>
    <li>The Human League</li>
    <li>The Tragically Hip</li>
    <li>Screaming Lord Sutch</li>
    <li>John Mayer</li>
    <li>UFO</li>
    <li>Edison Lighthouse</li>
    <li>Billy Corgan</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works well for some cases but the grid css is nice to keep the number sequence easier to read for multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class in the Advance settings named multicol and then experiment with screen sizes so it's user friendly on smaller screen sizes changing from 3 to 2 to 1 columns depending on screen size.

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .multicol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .multicol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .multicol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  }
}
```